# Netbeans MySql Database connection

Tags: mysql, database, netbeans

I am having trouble creating a connection to a MySql database in Netbeans. I cannot get anything to work.

1. I cannot create a MySql database in Netbeans

I visited the Netbeans Documentation. They were using a Mac and were referencing files that did not come with my installation of MySQL. They were referencing some file called mysql.admin. I right-clicked Databases in the services tab in Netbeans and clicked register MySQL Server. I am supposed to fill out the following form:

[image: Form]

However as stated earlier my machine apparently does not have this "admin tool" or any of these programs.

Ultimately I would like to migrate a Derby Database to MySQL. However the first step is to at least get a MySQL database working in Netbeans...

Comment: Are you trying to create a database or connect to one you already have setup? Otherwise you will need to install an instance of Mysql to your server.

Comment: I would like to first just create one. I do have a Derby Database that I would like to migrate to MySQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@CodeKingPlusPlus, and anyone facing this problem. If you are using linux, Enter the following in the textboxes specified in the **Admin Properties** Tab of the **MySQL Server Properties** dialog:

**Path to start command:** /usr/bin/mysql

**Arguments:** /etc/init.d/mysql start

**Path to Stop command:** /usr/bin/mysql

**Arguments:** /etc/init.d/mysql stop

For **MS Windows** users, refer to the path where your **bin** folder is situated.

e.g.

```
     C:\mysql\bin

     C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin

     Installation Folder~\xampp\mysql\bin
```

Also check out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25662912/2414129