# How can I connect MySQL to NetBeans on ubuntu?

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to connect MySQL Workbench to NetBeans in ubnutu 14.04. The problem is that I didn't know how to set the admin properties (Window->Services->Databases).I followed this [connecting MySQL server to NetBeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24081719/connecting-mysql-server-to-netbeans)

but I'm getting 'connection refused'.

What should I do to fix this??

Comment: you are trying to connect to mysql DB from netbeans, Or your workbench isn't connecting to MySql, Netbean and workbench both are developer tools.

Comment: I'm trying to connect Netbeans to mysql workbench, but it seems to be impossible because they are both developer tools, as you said.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to connect MySQL Workbench to NetBeans in ubnutu 14.04.

Workbench provides interface for `MySQL` Server. You can't connect to workbench. You need to connection of `MySQL` server

Show us what you tried so far in code.

Comment: Ah ok I'll try with MySQL and I'll tell you the result.