# Connecting a DB to NetBeans first time

Tags: java, mysql, database-connection, netbeans-8, sha2

This is a [repost](http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/jdbc-databases/41522-connecting-db-netbeans-first-time.html) from Java Programming Forum.  I am reposting here because I am concerned over low traffic.

To learn about databases, I am working through [this Murach book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1890774782) published in 2014.  I am using NetBeans 8.2, Tomcat 8.0, and I have two MySQL Servers installed, version 5.5 and version 8.0.  I also have MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE installed and a Tomcat 9.0.  I have gotten pre-built web applications to work with a Tomcat server.  The exercise I am working on is the final test run to make sure that all the software I need is correctly installed and configured.  At this point all I really know is Java.  I don't know anything about databases yet.  I've only blindly followed installation instructions.  This is the last thing I need to get working before I start learning stuff.

From the book:

> **Exercise 3-3: Run web applications that use a database**
>
> This exercise has you run two of the web applications presented in this
>   book that use a database.  This forces you to register the connections
>   for the two databases that are used by this book.  For this to work,
>   you must install and configure the MySQL database server as described
>   in appendix A (PC) or B (Mac).
>
> **Use the Murach database**
>
> 1. Open the ch12email project that's in the book_apps directory.
> 2. If that displays a dialog box that says the database connection needs to be registered with NetBeans, click on the Close button for
>      this dialog box.  Then right-click on the project, select the Resolve
>      Data Sources Problem item, and use the resulting dialog boxes to
>      resolve the data source problem and register the database connection
>      for the murach database.
> 3. Run the application to see how it works.  After you enter your name and email address and click on the Join Now button, your entries are
>      saved to a MySQL database.
> 4. ...
> 5. ...

I was able to open the project.
[image]

I did not get a database connection dialog box warning, but if I right click on the project, I can select Resolve Data Sources.  A dialog box opens which allows me to "Add Connection".
[image]

Doing so opens the New Connection Wizard.
[image]

While looking around for help on Stack Overflow, I ran into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36906045/2031150) suggestion:

> check the context.xml file in Web Pages -> META-INF, the
>   username="user" must be the same as the database user, in my case was
>   root, that solved the connection error

which prompted me to check these connection wizard login boxes against the context.xml.

My context.xml:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/murach" auth="Container" 
        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/murach" 
        username="murach_user" password="sesame" 
        maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" 
        logAbandoned="true" removeAbandoned="true" 
        removeAbandonedTimeout="60" type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
```

This information seems to match, but when I click on "Test Connection", I get this error:

> Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/murach
>   using com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (Unable to load authentication plugin
>   'caching_sha2_password'.)

Many of the answers I have found seem to suggest either creating a new database or editing an existing database, but as I've not yet built one myself, I wouldn't yet know how to do this.

---

The above statement is the basis of why I believe the popular solution link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50387952/how-to-resolve-unable-to-load-authentication-plugin-caching-sha2-password-issu), is not sufficient for me.  I'll continue to work at it, but there are too many unknown aspects of what a database is and how it works with everything else to be able to solve it easily.  This is getting into the weeds here, but I am now being asked to defend my question.  There is a world of difference between an answer like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52470141/2031150), and an answer like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50433762/2031150).  In the first answer, you barely need to know anything.  The second gives key information with an unspecified application.  Now it seems it is the answers that I have difficulty with and not the question, but I believe / hope the questions of each posting have elicited like answers.  Also, the suggested post is a question concerning Eclipse rather than NetBeans, and if that doesn't matter than I wouldn't know that either.

Comment: As I've not built my own database, I don't understand the top voted answer.  I guess this is sort of a chicken vs egg thing.  It seems I need to know how to fix it before I can understand anything.  The top answer says "Run the command..."  Run it where?  With what?  Is this Linux Bash?  Is this a command prompt in NetBeans?  Is this the MySQL command line?

Comment: In MySQL command line.

Comment: Which version of MySQL Connector/J are you using? You need to use at least version 5.1.46 IIRC

Comment: I am not sure if this is what you mean, but by going to: Project Properties -> Libraries -> MySQL JDBC Driver -> Edit, the Library Classpath is C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\ide\modules\ext\mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar

Comment: So I just need to install the MySQL Connector/J from [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.1.html)?  How do I replace the old one?  Is it part of the JDK, NetBeans, MySQL, Tomcat, or Glassfish?  Do I have to delete the old one, or do I just change settings somewhere in NetBeans?