# Netbeans cannot establish a connection to jdbc

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, netbeans

I'm trying to create a JDBC connection between a project in Netbeans and a MySQL database.  In the Netbeans connection wizard I receive the following

> error: Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/murach using com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (Unable to load authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password'.)

I'm running **Netbeans 8.2, MySQL 8.0.15** and **Java JDK 1.8.0_201**.  I am able to connect to the database using the credentials supplied in the wizard via the command prompt.

I also confirmed that port 3306 is open in Windows Firewall.

Comment: see if this helps, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24081719/connecting-mysql-server-to-netbeans

Comment: Is the error message really _"...using com.mysql.jdbc.Drive"_, or is that a typing error in your question? The driver class should be `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` rather than `com.mysql.jdbc.Drive`.

Comment: @skomisa Thanks for pointing that out, and after expanding the window, the full error message is: Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/murach using com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (Unable to load authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password'.)

Comment: @DaveH Check this out -->https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50387952/how-to-resolve-unable-to-load-authentication-plugin-caching-sha2-password-issu

Comment: [1] OK, please update the question accordingly. [2] Possible duplicate of [How to resolve Unable to load authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50387952/2985643). [3] The [solution given in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50433762/2985643) will probably resolve your problem.

Comment: I was able to resolve this by downgrading to MySQL 5.7.25

Answer (score 0):

make the driver something like com.mysql5.jdbc.Driver

Comment: I don't think a driver with that name exists. Can you post a link?

Comment: I was doing something with mysql and hibernate and I had to change the driver name from just mysql to mysql5